# CSS: Make the distance between bullets inside navigation menu smaller

Tags: html, css, list

I have a small problem with a styling my navigation menu.

So here is my HTML file:

```html
<ul class="main-ul">
    <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Article</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Blog</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Contcts</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is my CSS file:

```css
.main-ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 100px;
}
.main-ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgba(164, 164, 164, 0.2);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.main-ul li a span {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.9);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Kotta One', serif;
}
```

So if you insert it in [CSS Desk](http://cssdesk.com/) or any other online CSS editor you can see that distance between bullets in my navigation menu is big. I just can't understand why. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong and how can I make this distance smaller?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that there are no bullets at all. Did you mean that the items have too much space between them? In that case, it's simply because you set `.main-ul li` to `padding-left:100px`.

Answer (score 1):

You have set the left padding for the 'li'-elements to 100px. Use margin instead if you want an indented list.

Answer (score 1):

The `li` elements are declared with an exagerrated left padding. Have a smaller value and the problem is fixed:

```css
.main-ul li {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

You may also want to change the width to prevent content from bleeding to the right, e.g.:

```css
.main-ul li {
    width:150px;
}
```

Here's a [**live demo**](http://cssdesk.com/XZRXj).

Answer (score 0):

That's caused by `padding-left` of 100px in

```
.main-ul li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:10%;
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:100px;
}
```

Change that to a smaller number to decrease the spacing.